# Making an XML based config in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, configuration

I've been working on a basic XMLConfig with methods similar to those of SnakeYAML.

I've come across 2 problems: I don't know I'm going to work out mulch-layered paths to objects, and I have no idea how to read an actual object from a path (unless I tell it the type, for example a String).
I'm using DOM to parse my config File.

Problem 1:
Okay, so I've gotten something like this:

> ```
> public String getString(String string, String def) {
> return getRootElement().getElementsByTagName(string).item(0) == null || getRootElement().getElementsByTagName(string).item(0).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase("") ? def : getRootElement().getElementsByTagName(string).item(0).getTextContent();
> }
> ```

This works (unless it's not there, then I get an NPE even though I did a check?), but it will only work for 1 layer (if that is the correct term).

Example:

```
<root>
<somestring>hello!</somestring></root>
```

I can get the value of somestring by using getString("somestring", null).

However, if it was something like this:

```
<root>
<somestrings>
    <string>Hey!</string>
    <string2>Hola!</string>
</somestrings>
```

I have no way of getting string or string2, unless I get the nodelist, convert it to a string list, then get what I want. I would like to somehow return a String list, and just add all results in it, that's easy enough, but what about paths? How would I know how many times to loop through the children? I need some way of doing getString("somestrings.string", null).

Problem 2:
So, I can get a String list, but how would I get the object? 
I have this method:

```
    public List<String> getStringList(String string) {
return XMLUtils.NodeListToStringList(getRootElement().getElementsByTagName(string));
}
```

XMLUtils.NodeListToStringList() is:

```
public static List<String> NodeListToStringList(NodeList n) {
List<String> toReturn = Lists.newArrayList();
if (n == null) return toReturn;
for (int i = 0; i < n.getLength(); i++) {
    toReturn.add(n.item(i).getTextContent());
}
return toReturn;
}
```

Now how would I do the same, but return an Object list?
Pretty sure I'm missing out on something here.

Comment: What not use an attribute for each node that specifies the basic class type?